# transforming one xml using source xml using xsltproc

Tags: xml, xslt

probably a no brainer for the seasoned xslt experts among you but here goes:
I have 2 xml files strings.xml and strings-es.xml
I need to delete nodes that are in strings-es.xml but are not in strings.xml (the key is the name attribute)
e.g.

strings.xml:

```
<Resources>
   <!-- Strings for Dialog yes button -->
<string name="yes">"Yes"</string>

<!-- Strings for Dialog no button -->
<string name="no">"No"</string>

</Resources>
```

strings-es.xml

```
<Resources>
   <!-- Strings for Dialog yes button -->
<string name="yes">"Si"</string>

<!-- Strings for Dialog no button -->
<string name="no">"Non"</string>

<!-- Strings not used -->
<string name="not-important">"blabla"</string>

</Resources>
```

desired output:

```
<Resources>
   <!-- Strings for Dialog yes button -->
<string name="yes">"Si"</string>

<!-- Strings for Dialog no button -->
<string name="no">"Non"</string>


</Resources>
```

Comment: What about the comments? Should they be deleted along with the unwanted lines, i.e. is there any correspondence between them, is every `string` element preceded by a comment?

Comment: Also, your output does not match your description of what should happen. You say the name attribute is the key, but for all `string` elements in strings-es.xml, there exists a corresponding `string/@name` in strings.xml.

Comment: @mathias the comments are not important(I should have erased them from the output ...). the name is the key, I shall fix the required output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that "strings-es.xml" is the input XML, and "strings.xml" is an external document:

**Input XML**

```
<Resources>
   <!-- Strings for Dialog yes button -->
<string name="yes">"Si"</string>

<!-- Strings for Dialog no button -->
<string name="no">"Non"</string>

<!-- Strings not used -->
<string name="not-important">"blabla"</string>

</Resources>
```

Since you said that comments are unimportant, there is a separate template that prevents them from being sent to output.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="doc" select="doc('strings.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="string">
        <xsl:if test="$doc/Resources/string[@name = current()/@name]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Resources/comment()"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<Resources>
  <string name="yes">"Si"</string>
  <string name="no">"Non"</string>
</Resources>
```